Add points over bars in R
When creating a bar plot in plotly, it automatically offsets bars next to one another, but if I add points to the same plot, the points are not offset. How do I offset the points to match the bars?
library(dplyr)

plotly::plot_ly() %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(data = iris %>% 
                      dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
                      dplyr::summarize(y1 = mean(Sepal.Length),
                                       y2 = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
                      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c('y1', 'y2')),
                    x    = ~Species,
                    y    = ~value,
                    type        = 'bar', 
                    name        = ~name,
                    color       = ~name,
                    legendgroup = ~name,
                    # only show a single legend
                    showlegend  = TRUE) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    data = iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
      dplyr::summarize(y1 = mean(Sepal.Length),
                       y2 = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(y1 > 6) %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c('y1', 'y2')),
    x    = ~Species,
    y    = ~value,
    type      = 'scatter',
    mode      = 'markers',
    name        = ~name,
    color       = ~name,
    legendgroup = ~name,
    marker = list(size = 10)
  )


This makes me think that it is possible, but I don't see how to do it.

Maybe there is no way to do this easily in Plotly. This post recommends manually specifying x-axis values.

I would suggest making an equivalent plot in ggplot2 and then using ggplotly, if it produces broadly equivalent results

I don't know what the plotly native solution would be, but you can always use ggplotly and `position_dodge
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)


g <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(y1 = mean(Sepal.Length),
                    y2 = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c('y1', 'y2')) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=Species, y=value, fill = name), position="dodge") +
  geom_point(
    aes(Species, value, colour=name),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),
    data = iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
      dplyr::summarize(y1 = mean(Sepal.Length),
                       y2 = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(y1 > 6) %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c('y1', 'y2')))

ggplotly(g)



